# Can't find variable: _AutofillCallbackHandler

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Facing error on instagram browser(when open site in instagram for browsing). particularly on iphone devices.

Comment: I face the same error as many other people do: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/320013549791141/. However it might not affect user experience...

Comment: its not effecting but logs increased which effect performance

Answer (score 0):

```
window._AutofillCallbackHandler = window._AutofillCallbackHandler || function(){}
```

Solves the problem.

But I don’t know what part of the code tries to call this function.